# Select only a single column in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, select

The EntityModel is defined as:
*Personnel has a link to a Country*

When executing this code in LinqPad, I see that the SQL which is generated is not optimized (all fields are returned) in the first query ? What am I missing here or doing wrong ?

**Query 1 LINQ**

```
var Country = Countries.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 100000581);
var personnelIds = Country.Personnels.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
personnelIds.Dump();
```

**Query 1 SQL**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Version], [t0].[Identifier], [t0].[Name], , [t0].[UpdatedBy] FROM [Personnel] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Country_Id] = @p0',N'@p0 bigint',@p0=100000581
```

**Query 2 LINQ**

```
var Country = Countries.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 100000581);
var personnelIds2 = Personnels.Where(p => p.Country == Country).Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
personnelIds2.Dump();
```

**Query 2 SQL**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Id] FROM [Personnel] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Country_Id] = @p0',N'@p0 bigint',@p0=100000581
```

The database used is SQL Express 2008. And LinqPad version is 4.43.06

Answer (score 48):

```
//var Country = Countries.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 100000581);
var personnelIds = context.Personnels
    .Where(p => p.Country.Id == 100000581)
    .Select(p => p.Id)
    .ToArray();

personnelIds.Dump();
```

Try this, it should be better.

Comment: I actually want to retrieve the Personnels via the Country object as described in Query 1.

What I don't understand is that all columns are fetched, and not only the Id column

Answer (score 4):

Personnels collection will be populated via lazy loading when accessed, hence retrieving all of the fields from the DB.  Here's what's happening...

```
// retrieves data and builds the single Country entity (if not null result)
var Country = Countries.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 100000581);

// Country.Personnels accessor will lazy load and construct all Personnel entity objects related to this country entity object
// hence loading all of the fields
var personnelIds = Country.Personnels.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
```

You want something more like this:

```
// build base query projecting desired data
var personnelIdsQuery = dbContext.Countries
    .Where( c => c.Id == 100000581 )
    .Select( c => new
        {
            CountryId = c.Id,
            PersonnelIds = c.Personnels.Select( p => p.Id )
        }

// now do enumeration
// your example shows FirstOrDefault without OrderBy
// either use SingleOrDefault or specify an OrderBy prior to using FirstOrDefaul

var result = personnelIdsQuery.OrderBy( item => item.CountryId ).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR:

```
var result = personnelIdsQuery.SingleOrDefault();
```

Then get the array of IDs if not null

```
if( null != result )
{
    var personnelIds = result.PersonnelIds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try can also try grouping personnel into a single query

```
var groups =
    (from p in Personnel
     group p by p.CountryId into g
     select new 
     {
         CountryId = g.Key
         PersonnelIds = p.Select(x => x.Id)
     });
var personnelIds = groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == 100000581);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ForeignKey explicitly defined in your POCO for Personnel? It's common to leave it out in EF, but adding it would massively simplify both this code and the resulting SQL:

```
public class Personnel
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    . . .
}

> update-database -f -verbose

var ids = db.Personnel.Where(p => p.CountryId == 100000581).Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
```